# Cookie Not Being Set Remotely But Working Fine Locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, heroku

I'm doing a simple django app, and needed to make sure my csrftoken was being set properly so that I could post responses.

When I test locally, and look at my javascript debugging, all is right with the world, and the csrf is attached properly. But when I look at the exact same breakpoint running in Heroku, the entire getCookie function returns a blank. FYI, I'm using the standard getCookie function from the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/):

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Other jQuery and javascript is working properly on the page, but, in this case, document.cookie  is completely empty.

I've tried it from a bunch of different domains (herokuapp.com, domain_name, etc), but all the same. Why would document.cookie be emtpy? Shouldn't SOMETHING be in there?

Comment: Are you running in HTTPS on heroku?

Comment: I'm accessing the site via http:, is there some default setting that forces https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Django (for unknown reasons) did not like submitting the X Header, so I broke down and put:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

At the top of my template. And added:

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('csrfmiddlewaretoken').val()};
```

To the passback data. Ugly, but it worked.